# Anyway to always return null/empty value for a mysql column with performance in mind?

Tags: mysql, string, performance, null

I have a sharded database that is a a result from multi able sources, but some do not have data for all of the common columns. I shard base on source, so the whole resulting table current gets a column char(1) and all values set to ''. Once data is imported, it's read only with rare exceptions.

Is there a better way performance wise to tell mysql to always return a null or '' result for the given column? I tested char(0), but it forces a table scan. Prefer not to have to look up table layout to static select the column (SELECT '' as ip).

With results (ip)

```
CREATE TABLE `shard1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `message` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `ip` varchar(39) NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `type` (`type`),
 KEY `ip` (`ip`,`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Without results (ip)

```
 CREATE TABLE `shard2` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     `message` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     `ip` char(1) NOT NULL
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `type` (`type`),
     KEY `ip` (`ip`,`type`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Selects are typically like this

```
SELECT type,message,ip FROM shard1 WHERE id = 123;
SELECT message,ip FROM shard1 WHERE ip = '127.0.0.1';
SELECT message,ip FROM shard1 WHERE type = 'error' and ip = '127.0.0.1';
```

This is an overly simplified representation of the system. Smallest shard table is as little as 27 rows, and the biggest one is over 500m rows. Performance currently is acceptable, around 0.05 secs but I'd always love to make things more efficient.

Comment: I don't see what the contents of a record have to do with the logic of looking up that record.  `to always return a null or '' result` ... can you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: Some of the tables do not have ip addresses, but searches can be performed on the ip column. A null or '' result would work for the software. The char(0) test was in hopes the mysql query optimizer would be smart enough to know that only 1 value was possible and skip the table scan.

Comment: how about `select message, NULL ip FROM shard1`

Comment: I'm trying to get the blank/null result from the table design. If I statically selected null as ip, then I'd have to map which tables contain ip and which ones don't.

Comment: "Sharding" is intended for splitting the data across multiple servers, not a single server.  What is your goal??

Answer (score 0):

Seems I figured out a possible solution using a view with a static empty string as ip. Never really used views before but the optimizer is smart enough in a view, but not in the main table.

View `test` was created on this statement

```
SELECT id,type,message,'' as ip FROM shard2
```

Optimizer is smart enough to know any search but '' will result in no results even WHERE ip LIKE '%anything%' is instant (0.001 sec) even without an index for ip on a 10m row table I'm testing with.

```
SELECT message,ip FROM test WHERE ip LIKE '%1';
```

Also to explain the statement the optimizer sees it's an "impossible WHERE" so the software effectively gets no results from the table.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Impossible WHERE
```

Learn something new everyday I guess.

Comment: Fake news.  "Impossible WHERE" means that _EXPLAIN_ discovered that no `ip` ended in `1`.  _That_ took time (a table scan) during the `EXPLAIN`, and it would take time (a table scan) when doing the `SELECT`.

Comment: If I run the same query on the table, it takes ~6 seconds, if I run it on the view it's 0.00 seconds. I might not be an expert, but I don't think explain examines the index's, it just tells you want indexes it would use giving the question asked. Here is an example of an explain on a full table scan (only 944 rows in the table). Format might be bad since I can't figure out how to add a line break in these comments. id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
1  SIMPLE  db_info  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 944  Using where

Comment: Run it twice in a row -- does it take 6 seconds the first time?  And only milliseconds the second time?  If so, that is the effect of the "Query Cache".  Again Fake News.

Comment: Don't remember which exact table I used before, but picked a random 10m row one with no ips. Searching WHERE ip like '%1' runs 1.7551 seconds for the first time, second time it runs 1.7631 seconds. Currently the table lives on a SSD so table scans are pretty fast, but doing that 100x is slow. Oddly, explain doesn't show it using the index at all and seems to be doing a full table scan.

Comment: That's right.  `LIKE "%1"` is a leading wild card.  Hence, the index is useless.  It's like looking up "James" using `LIKE "%s"` to find names ending in `s`.

Comment: Why do you need to do `LIKE '%1'` a thousand times?  Let's rethink what and how to do that.  Meanwhile, it will take 1.7s _each time_ to scan the million rows.

Comment: It's purely for testing reasons, with the table view, the optimizer sees the where statement is impossible to satisfy, so it returns 0 results with out even looking at the data. The tables have more info than just ip, it's just one of the fields, sometimes there's a post fix search needed on other columns which I have a virtual column indexed that is the string reversed to work around the table scan problem in that case. The question was posted for char(0) fields, and to have the optimizer basally give no results instantly because of the field definition, that's all I care about.